# How can I install Blender 2.76 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, blender

I'd like to install Blender 2.76 on Ubuntu 14.04, but it's not officially available from the Ubuntu repos.

How can I install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the unofficial PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

The above commands will install Blender version 2.76b, which has several bug fixes.